# How to request WFS propertyName containing parentheses

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I'm trying to call getFeature with a list of property names, not including the geometry column. I'm getting this frustrating error message for a property that includes a parenthesis:

Requested property: abstudy_(living_allowance) is not available for dss_payments_sa2_q4_2017.  The possible propertyName values are: [sa2_code, sa2_name, abstudy_(living_allowance), ....

The URL in question looks like this

```
.../wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=JSON&request=GetFeature&typeName=dss_payments_sa2_q4_2017&maxFeatures=5&propertyName=abstudy_%28living_allowance%29
```

WFS 1.1.0 from GeoServer.

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple dataset into PostGIS with your attribute name and noticed that browsers do not parse the response. They claim that XML is invalid and locate the error to character #989 which is the starting parenthesis in here

```
cite:abstudy_(living_allowance)
             ^
```

I spent some time for finding a reference that explains why the attribute name is not valid but it was not so simple. If you want to continue here is the complete XML from GetFeature but it feels to me that you must rename your attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:cite="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="2" timeStamp="2018-08-07T12:58:49.593Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=cite%3Alinetest http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><gml:featureMembers><cite:linetest gml:id="linetest.1"><cite:wkb_geometry><gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#404000" srsDimension="2"><gml:lineStringMember><gml:LineString gml:id="null.1"><gml:posList>453 683 598 736 564 636 453 683</gml:posList></gml:LineString></gml:lineStringMember></gml:MultiLineString></cite:wkb_geometry><cite:abstudy_(living_allowance)>f</cite:abstudy_(living_allowance)></cite:linetest><cite:linetest gml:id="linetest.2"><cite:wkb_geometry><gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#404000" srsDimension="2"><gml:lineStringMember><gml:LineString gml:id="null.1"><gml:posList>316 663 422 621 310 610 316 663</gml:posList></gml:LineString></gml:lineStringMember></gml:MultiLineString></cite:wkb_geometry><cite:abstudy_(living_allowance)>f</cite:abstudy_(living_allowance)></cite:linetest></gml:featureMembers></wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I think that's the issue. Unfortunately it's not my attribute to rename.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error the answer seems to be: wrap the propertyName in double quotes: `"` (`%22`):

```
...&propertyName=%22abstudy_%28living_allowance%29%22
```

EDIT

Actually no. The error goes away but it doesn't actually return the property data.

Comment: While this may work type names are not allowed to contain '()' as they must be [XML names](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html). I thought that GeoServer "fixed" those names but I guess not.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed"? Replacing the ( and ) with something else?

Comment: Also, just clarifying the issue is about property names, not type names. And it turns out this doesn't "work" exactly. The error goes away, but the property is still not actually returned.